# How to add active class to the navbar based on the scroll position in Angular 4?

Tags: angular

I would like to highlight the active section in the menu. Similar to this:
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/scrollspy/

I tried this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-scrollspy but it looks like it's only compatible with Angular 2 and not the latest version.

I'm also loading bootstrap 4 library.

**Navigation menu**

```
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#other1">Other1</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Content**

```
<h1 id="about">About</h1>
...
<h1 id="contact">Contact</h1>
...
<h1 id="other1">Other1</h1>
```

Comment: The `ng2-scrollspy` package is compatible with angular version `^4.0.2`.

Comment: When I try to use that plugin i'm getting an error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined` on this line `this.scrollSpyService.getObservable('window').subscribe((e: any) => {`

Comment: Did you add the `scrollSpy` directive (`<nav scrollSpy> ...`) and follow the install instructions? Because `getObservable('window')` is `undefined` when the directive is not used.

Comment: Can you add the code to your question where `this.scrollSpyService.getObservable` is used?

Comment: And keep in mind that the package name has changed to `ngx-scrollspy`.

Comment: Thanks, its working now, but I'm still unsure how I can set the class `active` using this plugin.

Comment: Did you take a look at the [plugins](https://github.com/JonnyBGod/ngx-scrollspy/tree/master/src/plugin) the library is providing.